Consider $x^5-5x+1=0$. Show by Contraction Principle that there exists a unique solution in the interval $[-1,1]$ & find it with an error $<10^{-3}$
I thought of using $f′(x)=5x^4−5$. Then $5x^4−5=0$ and determine the critical points $1$ and $−1$. I know that between consecutive real roots of $f$ there is a real root of $f'$, but I'm not sure what to do further.

See also this question.

You should combine this with your other question.  But use $IVT$ to show that as $f(-1)= 5>0$ and $f(1)=-3 < 0$ there must be at least one root in the interval.  Use that $f('x) \ne 0$ for $x\in (-1,1)$ to show there are no critical points so there is at most one solution (if there were two or more there'd be a real root of $f'$ but there isn't).  Then hone in.  $f(0)>1$ so root is $0<r <1$.  $f(\frac 12)=\frac 1{32}-\frac 52+1<0$ so the root is $0< r<\frac 12$.  For $r<\frac 12$, $x^5$ is teeny so $f(x)\approx -5x+1$ so try $f(0.2)$ next and hone it to three decimal points.....

.... $f(0.2) = 0.0016>0$ That's almost but not quite good enough.  But we can use then $f(x)\approx f'(0.2)(x - 0.2) + f(0.2)$ and set that to $0$ and solve for $x$ and that'll probably be within $10^{-1}$

@fleablood Why not good enough?  $f'(0.2)$ is pretty close to $-5$, so the correction in the next iteration of Newton-Raphson will be approximately $+f(0.2) / 5 \approx 0.0005$ which is within $10^{-3}$.

@DanielSchepler Why not good enough?  Because $f(0.2)= 0.0016 > 10^{-3}$.  But .... oops I made an error and actually calculated $5x^4 -5x + 1= 0.0016$ when $x=0.2$.  Actually $f(0.2) = 0.2^5 -5\times 0.2 + 1=0.2^5 = 0.00032 < 10^{-3}$ and that fine.  We can do an even tighter approx but at $a=0.2$, $f(x)\approx'f'(0.2)(x-0.2)+f(0.2)=-4.992x + 0.9984 + 0.00032$.  Setting to $0$ and solving gives us $x=0.20006$ and $f(0.20006)=3.288364773793686575150420565108e-10$ which is closer than we could hope in our wildest dreams.

@fleablood I thought the problem was clear that it was asking for the unique solution to within an error of $10^{-3}$, not for a value $x_0$ with $|f(x_0)| < 10^{-3}$.

@DanielSchepler.  For sure.  I was just going overboard.  I got to $x\approx 0.2$ without really using the derivative/slope approximation.  I wanted to give an example of using the derivative slope approximation... which took us way finer than we were asked to go.  I seems the problem was deliberately set up to be calculation light.  Guess $0$ as midpoint to hone the root between $0$ and $1$. Guess $\frac 12$ to hone between $0$ and $\frac 12$. Note $x< \frac 12\implies x^5 < \frac 1{32}$ to do a crude $f(x)\approx -5x+1$ to get $x\approx 0.2$ which should be crude, but isn't.

Back to the original question. It says to use the "contraction principal".  You may or may not want to see this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325059/polynomial-root-using-contraction-mapping-principle or this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3330340/how-to-prove-that-a-polynomial-has-one-exactly-one-root-using-banachs-fixed-poi.  Or maybe not.  Seems a really complicated way to do it when Critical points and IVT and approximating slopes are MUCH easier.  (Or maybe I'm just not familiar enough with "contraction principle"-- never heard of it, myself)

The approximate value of the root is $x = 1/5$.

Put $f(x) = x^5 -5x+1$. Then $f(-1) > 0$ and $f(1)<0$ and $f(x)$ is continious. Thus $f(a)$ for some $a \in (-1,1)$.

Suppose there exists $b \in [-1,1]$ such that $b \ne a$ and $f(b)$. Hence $f(a) = f(b) = 0$. So there exists $c$ strictly between $a$ and $b$ such that $f'(c) = 0$. Thus $c \in (-1,1)$ and $f'(c)=0$. But $f'(c) = 5c^4 - 5 = 5(c^4-1) \ne 0$ for $c \in (-1,1)$. We got a contradiction.


Corollary: there exists only one root on $[-1,1]$.

Consider points $x_i = \frac{i}{2000}$ for $i \in \{-2000, -1999, \ldots, 1999, 2000 \}$. Consider the sequence $f(x_{-2000}), f(x_{-1999}), \ldots, f(x_{2000})$. We have $f(x_i) > 0$ for $i=-2000$ and $f(x_i)$ for $i=2000$. So there exists number $j$ such that $f(x_j) > 0$ and $f(x_{j+1}) \le 0$. Hence $f(x)$ has a root on $[x_j, x_{j+1}]$. Hence $x_j \approx $root with error $\le \frac{1}{2000} < \frac{1}{1000}$.

It's convenient to use computer to find such a $j$.


In Python:
def f(x):
  return x**5 - 5*x + 1

for j in range(-2000,2000): 
    if f(j/2000)> 0 and f((j+1)/2000) <= 0:
        print(j)
        break

We see that $j=400$ and $x_j = 400/2000 = 1/5$.
Hence the approximate value of the root is $x = 1/5$. The answer is $x = 1/5$.

But x=1/5 does not output $0$ when put in the equation?

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad Yes, the question was about an approximate value of the root. I made an addition.

For the unicity, I thought to prove that there exists $0<k<1$ such that for all $x,y\in[-1,1]$, $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq k|x-y|$. Then $|f'(x)|=|5x^4-5|=5(|x|^4+1)\leq 5(1+1)=10$. Since $|f'(x)|\leq 10$ for $x\in[-1,1]$ => $f(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous on [-1,1] and by Contraction Principle f(x) las a unique $x^$ in $[-1,1]$ i.e. $f(x^)=x^*$, a unique solution to $x^5-5x+1=0$ in $[-1,1]$.

@Rika But in Contraction Priciple we need $k < 1$, and here we have $k = \sup_{x \in [-1,1]}|f'(x)| = 10$.
